# Member search function

Tags: php, mysql, search

Im trying to come up with MySQL logic for a search function I got on my page. Its a simple form where the user can choose to fill in search criteria. The criteria(s) is send as arguments to a function that generates the mysql logic. This is whats inside the PHP controller file:

```
   case 'search':
         if((empty($_POST['username'])) && (empty($_POST['firstname'])) && (empty($_POST['lastname']))
                && (empty($_POSt['agemin'])) && (empty($_POST['agemax'])) && (empty($_POST['country']))){
                $members = get_all_username();
         } else {
            if(isset($_POST['username'])){
                $otheruser = $_POST['username'];
            } else { $otheruser = null; }
            if(isset($_POST['agemin'])){
                $ageMin = $_POST['agemin'];
            } else { $ageMin = null; }
            if(isset($_POST['agemax'])){
                $ageMax = $_POST['agemax'];
            } else { $ageMax = null; }
            if(isset($_POST['country'])){
                $country = $_POST['country'];
            } else { $country = null; }
            //if(isset($_POST['isonline']))

        $members = search_members($otheruser, $ageMin, $ageMax, $country);
        }
        include('displaySearch.php');
        break;
```

So if nothing is set a complete list of all the members is generated and displayed. This is the function that is called if any of the inputs is set:

```
function search_members($username, $ageMin, $ageMax, $country){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT username FROM profiles WHERE username = :username 
        AND age > :ageMin AND age < :ageMax AND country = :country";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username); $statement->bindValue(':ageMin', $ageMin);
    $statement->bindValue(':ageMax', $ageMax); $statement->bindValue(':country', $country);
    $statement->execute();
    if($statement->rowCount() >= 1){
        return $statement->fetchAll();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The mysql logic is obviously wrong. **I need a set of conditions (in the MySQL logic if possible) that checks the PHP variables for value and if there is none it should not be accounted for when querying the database.** So if only the username is set in the form the other variables should not be included in the SQL logic.

I've looked up the MySQL IF() condition but Im still not able to come up with proper code that does what I need. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be able to do the rest myself. Any other approach for solving this kind of problem is also welcome.

Comment: What are the conditions you are checking for?

Comment: Check if the PHP variable has a user input value or set to null (done in the controller php file). I think the solution given by DTukans is good. Concatenate sql logic depending on if it the PHP variable is null or not. I will try that and come back with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your problem, then the simple way is to use if else to build sql query, for example

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM profiles WHERE 1 "
if (!is_null($username)) {
    $sql .= " AND username = :username ";
}
// All other checks
```

Comment: This should work but I got a little problem. The null value that is assigned to the variables if the user does not input anything in a form is an empty string "" when var_dump and the condition !is_null($var) becomes true. I var_dump() both the form: string(7) "subzero" 
string(0) "" 
string(0) "" 
string(0) "" this result is produced when the user only choose to input one of the forms. The other variables are set to null; due to no input. The problem I get is that !is_null($var) returns true and wrong string is concatenated to the SQL logic.

Comment: Okay I came up with a solution. I used empty instead but would still like to know how to give a variable the value null so that I can use is_null in the future. $var = null; produced an empty string like this "". Thanks for the help. Cant upvote because I dont have 15 reputation :/